# How to specify obligatory element with specific name

Tags: xml, xsd

Let's say there is following XML structure

`<Autos>
<Auto>A</Auto>
<Auto>B</Auto>
<Auto>C</Auto>
</Autos>`

How to make an XSD with following rules:
`Autos` can have any any number of elements `Auto`.
`Autos` must one element `Auto` with value A.

Elements `Auto` have to be in an unordered list.

Attempted solutions:
I've tried using xsd elements choice, all, and sequence, but haven't been able to create valid solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XML tree structure, the text within an element is a child of the element node. XML Schema validates an element by only looking at its immediate children, not its children's children. So when `<Autos>` is validated, it only sees `<Auto>` `<Auto>` `<Auto>` and not the text child nodes.

To make the validation of `<Autos>` enforce your rules, you'd have to use different names to distinguish each Auto, such as `<AutoA>`, ...

Or if the XML is fixed, the "validation" would have to happen outside XML Schema, such as in a stylesheet or program logic.